# Part over navigation bar has different background color

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am really struggling figuring out why there's a part on top of the navigation bar that has a different color than the navigation bar.

I have set the navigation like this:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .primaryBlack
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

And for some reason only one part is with that color but not everything. In some other parts that part is completely transparent making it look really odd.

[image]

Comment: Tried UINavigationBarAppearance() ??

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when ever my navigation bar is using large titles and push a view controller onto the navigation stack of the navigation controller, this gap seems to be at the top:

[image: UINavigationBar different color to status bar swift iOS UINavigationController]

There seems to be some gap created for some reason and the large title navigation bar starts under the status bar.

The reason I understand as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/3198027-scrolledgeappearance) is that the base view goes under the UINavigationBar and when this view is scrolled, the UINavigationBar needs to transform.

> When a navigation controller contains a navigation bar and a scroll
> view, part of the scroll view’s content appears underneath the
> navigation bar. If the edge of the scrolled content reaches that bar,
> UIKit applies the appearance settings in this property.

Simplest thing I do is to make the underlying view the same color as the navigation bar background in the view controller and keep the result of your code the same:

```
// Same as your code, only changed background to blue
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .blue
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

// What I added
view.backgroundColor = .blue
```

This gives me:

[image: UINavigationBar has different background color to status bar iOS swift]

**Update using `UINavigationBarAppearance`**

Can you try updating using `UINavigationBarAppearance`

```
// From your code, not sure of it's purpose
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

// Color of the nav bar background
appearance.backgroundColor = .black // primary black for you

// Color for the titles
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes
    = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]

appearance.titleTextAttributes
    = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]

navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance

// Color for the back button
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```

Result:

[image: UINavigationBar navigation bar different color from status bar swift]

Comment: I've tried that on the view controllers and it didn't work, the space seems to be transparent still.

Comment: @JoanCardona - please see my update using `UINavigationBarAppearance`